# wget does not download to the specified directory in windows

Tags: python, windows, wget

I'm trying to download a file using wget in python code in Windows.

```
os.system("bash -c '" + 'wget -r -l1 -c -nc --no-parent -nd -P ' + chrombased_npy_path + ' ftp://example.com/' + filename + "'")
```

I'm expecting to download the file under given *chrombased_npy_path*

However, under the current working directory it generates a directory called *chrombased_npy_path* discarding all slashes and download the file under that.

Is there a way to download the file under *chrombased_npy_path* in windows?

Comment: chrombased_npy_path should be an absolute path.

Comment: This code works in linux as expected.

Comment: @MichaelButscher chrombased_npy_path is absolute path it is interpreted so in linux however in windows slashes are discarded and not interpreted as absolute path.

Comment: os.path.isabs(chrombased_npy_path) returns True in windows. In the command, it removes all the slashes and  take it as a relative path. command: os.system("bash -c '" + 'wget -r -l1 -c -nc --no-parent -nd -P ' + chrombased_npy_path + ' ftp://example.com/' + filename + "'")

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: assign command to variable - ie.  `cmd = "bash -c '" + 'wget ...` and display it `print(cmd)` to see if you have correct command. And then you can even copy displayed text to run it directly in sytem to see if it works. Maybe it will need backslashes instead slashes.

Comment: It does not give error. In the cmd, C:\Users\burcak\Developer\Python\SigProfilerTopography\SigProfilerTopography\lib\nucleosome\chrbased becomes C:UsersburcakDeveloperPythonSigProfilerTopographySigProfilerTopographylibnucleosomechrbased in windows.

Comment: Here is the cmd: bash -c 'wget -r -l1 -c -nc --no-parent -nd -P C:\Users\burcak\Developer\Python\SigProfilerTopography\SigProfilerTopography\lib\nucleosome\chrbased ftp://alexandrovlab-ftp.ucsd.edu/pub/tools/SigProfilerTopography/lib/nucleosome/chrbased/chr17_signal_wgEncodeSydhNsomeGm12878Sig.npy'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to download a file to a certain directory which is an absolute path (**chrombased_npy_path**)  in python  code on Windows using the following command:

```
os.system("bash -c '" + 'wget -r -l1 -c -nc --no-parent -nd -P ' + chrombased_npy_path + ' ftp://example.com/' + filename + "'")
```

Although this command was working on a linux machine properly, on Windows, it was removing all the slashes from  given target path (**chrombased_npy_path**) and downloading the file to 
a directory **chrombased_npy_path slashes removed version** under current working directory.

To get rid of this problem, I changed directory to **chrombased_npy_path** and then download the file to the current directory without providing the target path.

```
os.chdir(chrombased_npy_path)
os.system("bash -c '" + 'wget -r -l1 -c -nc --no-parent -nd ftp://example.com/' + filename + "'")
```